# Joomla administrator redirects to public site

Tags: joomla

I have a Joomla site running on a windows machine.  The site was at 1.6 when some update requests came in.  I decided to update the site, but the automated process didn't work, so I started FTPing the files up there manually.

I followed the instructions for the manual upgrade at http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_1.6.5_to_1.7 once I got the site to 1.6.5, but my problems had already started before that.

Now when I go to mysite.com/administrator most images are not there and when I try to log in I get kicked up to my site root rather than the /administrator folder.  I took the opportunity to look at the code and none of the image src attributes or the form action attributes include "/administrator".

Soooo I need a little advice as to why this is happening.  I would rather not have to restore from my backup and start over at 1.6.  I was kinda hoping for this to be my first Joomla 3 site.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I had this client move their Joomla install off Windows and onto a Linux machine.  Things were just getting worse with the install and I threw in the towel.  Thanks to Lodder for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

1. You said that you had trouble with updating Joomla via the admin panel, however did you check if the folders were writable? `Site -> System Information -> Directory Permissions` Always check this page once you have installed Joomla as it is the reason why a lot of people are unable to install updates or normal extensions.
2. You then mentioned that you had to upload the files manually via the FTP, however this is not requires. All that is required it to upload the update.zip to the foot of your Joomla site and unzip it.

As for a proper answer, May I suggest that you first update to the Latest version of the 1.6 series (1.6.6), then you download a fresh copy of Joomla 1.6.6, unzip the "administrator" folder, zip that folder, upload via the FTP to your Joomla root folder, then extract it. This will override all the default administrator files.

Comment: I'm currently at version 1.7.0.  I can get into the administrator interface if I change the form action attribute to include "/administrator".  The folders are all writeable.  When I was attemting to upgrade from 1.6.0 I did try to use the extension manager, but I received some sort of error and went the manual route.

I downloaded and extracted 1.7.0 and uploaded the zipped up the administrator folder.  I extracted it in my site root, but the problem still persists.  It seems to me that this should be some sort of setting somewhere.

Comment: ok, now that you are at 1.7, ensure you upgrade to 2.5 to start off with. No, this isn't a setting, it should not be happening. It is possible that an extension is causing the problem. Have you been editing any core Joomla files?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you are using the JSecure plugin. It requires a token in the URL to enter the admin panel, for example:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/administrator?token
```

Explanation:

http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2198164

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by removing the value that I had in the `$live_site` variable in the configuration.php file. I am also running this on a Windows server.