# Joomla 3.7 administration link doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, redirect, joomla3.7

I have strange problem on my joomla 3.7, administration link is not working any more it is re-directing to home page.

http://www.nnf-events.co.uk/administrator --> http://www.nnf-events.co.uk/

No idea why, I checked the htaccess file and everything looks fine I also read the if you have plugin jsecure it can be problem but I don+t have it installed.

Any suggestions ?

Br, Aljaž.

Comment: I have checked in the chrome console window. Found that there is '302 Moved temporary' for administrator link. Which means you need to check first with network team(i.e, route of your links). Second you need to check in the program level(i.e,need to check some core files first)

Comment: Hi Kaif, thanks for reply, network guys meaning that something is not ok on cpanel configuration ? Like some kind of redirection or something like that ?

Comment: I had come across on this issue on google, seams this issue occurs only on installing JSecure plugIn. Can you please check this link and try to follow that instructions(http://www.itoctopus.com/admin-page-in-joomla-redirects-to-homepage). Or recheck on htaccess, If you not found at this two areas, then need to check on code level(Need to debug)

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your help, I don't have JSecure plugin installed. And here is .htaccess files - https://codeshare.io/GqnLNR

I am not sure what is wrong here, I also have this log:
 05:43 PM
Info Gantry 5 update to version 5.4.12 went wrong 03/05/2017 01:17 PM
Info eventbooking update to version 2.14.4 went wrong 03/05/2017 01:16 PM
Info System - Akeeba GeoIP provider plugin has been updated (1.0.6 => 2.0.0) 03/05/2017 01:16 PM
Info Admin Tools package update to version 4.1.3 went wrong 03/05/2017 01:16 PM
Info Akeeba Backup package update to version 5.3.4 went wrong

Comment: Please go through the below links, might be you will get the answer to your problem.https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/20581/administrator-login-page-redirect-to-home-page. another link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807984/joomla-administrator-redirects-to-public-site

Answer (score 0):

my apologies  ask this question client had the tooken generated but didn't sent me the correct link. :( So there was nothing wrong with any of the plugins or something like that. Sorry again and thanks for help.

BR, Aljaž.